# Exact-match, case-insensitive match without normalization in Elasticsearch 6.2

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive, exact-match

I have looked at every article and post I could find about performing exact-match, case-insensitive queries, but upon implementation, they do not perform what I am looking for.

**Before you mark this question as a duplicate, please read the entire post.**

Given a username, I want to query my Elasticsearch database to only return a document that exactly matches the username, but is also case insensitive.

I have tried specifying a `lowercase` analyzer for my `username` property and use a `match` query to implement this behavior. While this solves the problem of case insensitive matching, it fails at exact matching.

I looked into using a `lowercase` normalizer, but that would make all of my usernames lowercase before indexing, so when I aggregate the usernames, they would return in lowercase form, which is not what I want. I need to preserve the original case of each letter in the username.

## What I want is the following behavior:

---

#### Inserting Users

```json
POST {elastic}/users/_doc
{
    "email": "random@email.com",
    "username": "UsErNaMe",
    "password": "1234567"
}
```

This document will be stored in an index called `users` exactly the way it is.

#### Getting a User by Username

```json
GET {frontend}/user/UsErNaMe
```

should return

```json
{
    "email": "random@email.com",
    "username": "UsErNaMe",
    "password": "1234567"
}
```

and

```json
GET {frontend}/user/username
```

should return

```json
{
    "email": "random@email.com",
    "username": "UsErNaMe",
    "password": "1234567"
}
```

and

```json
GET {frontend}/user/USERNAME
```

should return

```json
{
    "email": "random@email.com",
    "username": "UsErNaMe",
    "password": "1234567"
}
```

and

```json
GET {frontend}/user/UsErNaMe $RaNdoM LeTteRs
```

should **NOT** return anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To achieve case insensitive exact match you need to define you own analyzer. The analyzer need to perform two actions:

1. lowercase the input value. (for case insensitive)
2. no to any modification to the input after lowercase action. (for exact search)

The above two can be achieve by:

1. use `lowercase` filter when defining custom analyzer.
2. set the `tokenizer` to `keyword`, this will make sure to generate single token of the input value after lowercase filter is applied.

Now this custom analyzer can be applied to a text field where case insensitive exact search is required.

So to create index you can use below:

```json
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "username": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "case_insensitive_analyzer"
        },
        "password": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above `case_insensitive_analyzer` is the required analyzer and as you can see it is applied on `username` field.

So when you index a document as below:

```json
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "email": "random@email.com",
  "username": "UsErNaMe",
  "password": "1234567"
}
```

for the field `username` the input is `UsErNaMe`. The analyzer first applies `lowercase` filter on the input `UsErNaMe` resulting into the value `username`. Now on this value `username` it applies `keyword` tokenizer which does nothing but output the value obtained after applying filter(s), as a single token i.e. `username`.

Now you can use match query as below to search against user name field:

```json
GET test/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "username": "USERNAME"
    }
  }
}
```

Using above will give you desired output. Replace `USERNAME` in above query to `username` or `UsErNaMe` or `USERname` all will match the document. The reason for this is that while searching if no analyser is explicitly specified, elasticsearch uses the analyzer applied to the field while indexing. In the above case when searching against field `username`, `case_insensitive_analyzer` will be applied to input value i.e. `USERNAME` which will result in token `username` and hence the match.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try this already and I thought it did not work, but it turns out I forgot to switch to a match query for one of my routes in my service. Once I made all the necessary changes, everything worked perfectly.