# Right way for user search by partial username or name using ngram tokenizer in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, social-networking, n-gram

I want to create search fature for [social networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_networking_service) application in such a way that users can search other users by username or name even by inputting part of username or name using [elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch).

For example:

```
input: okma
result: {"username": "alokmahor", "name": "Alok Singh Mahor"} // partial match in username

input: m90
result: {"username": "ram9012", "name": "Ram Singh"} // partial match in username

input: shn
result: {"username": "r2020", "name": "Krishna Kumar"} // partial match with name
```

After reading and playing these links I come up with my partial solution which I am not sure if thats the correct way.

I followed
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html
[How to search for a part of a word with ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch)

My solution is

```
DELETE my_index

PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username":   { "type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"  },
      "name":   { "type": "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"  } 
    }
  }
}


PUT /my_index/_doc/1
{
  "username": "alokmahor",
  "name": "Alok Singh Mahor"
}

PUT /my_index/_doc/2
{
  "username": "ram9012",
  "name": "Ram Singh"
}

PUT /my_index/_doc/3
{
  "username": "r2020",
  "name": "Krishna Kumar"
}

GET my_index/_search
{
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "shn",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
      "fields": ["username", "name"]
    }
  }
}
```

somehow this solution is partailly working and I am not sure if this is really a correct way as I got this after playing aorund elasticsearch features and copy pasting example code. So please suggest correct way or improvement on this.

Things which are not working

```
// "sin" is not matching with "Singh" but "Sin" is matching and working.
GET my_index/_search
{
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sin",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
      "fields": ["username", "name"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: have you improved the index creation? Username searching works with this setup, I am wondering if you improved it more

Answer (score 1):

> So please suggest correct way

The degree of correctness can only be defined by your requirement. You can keep on refining by checking all the possible use cases one by one.

> improvement on this

For the problem you mention where `Sin` is matching while `sin` is not; this is because the analyzer defined doesn't make the search case-insensitive. To do so add lowercase filter in your analyzer definition as below:

```
  "analyzer": {
    "my_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    }
  }
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742477/exact-match-case-insensitive-match-without-normalization-in-elasticsearch-6-2/55743326#55743326) can help you understand more in case-insensitive search.